# EditText in ListView loses content in scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've been digging to find a solution on my problem finding answers but none of them have worked for me. :/
I have a listview with edittext in each list item and when scrolling down and go up again content of the edited edittext has been lost or other edittext has taken his value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWu0H.png

I have a global textWatcher and adding and removing it dynamically. Edittexts keep losing the content.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    ArrayPosition = position;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) AdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_order, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.FlightTimeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemFlightTimeTextView);
        holder.BusNumberEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busNumberEditText);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Order order = Orders.get(position);
    holder.FlightTimeTextView.setText(order.getFlightTime());

    holder.BusNumberEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    Log.d("String in array String", HolderBusNumbers[position]);
    holder.BusNumberEditText.setText(HolderBusNumbers[position]);

    holder.BusNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    return convertView;
}

int ArrayPosition = 0;
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d("TextWatcher", s.toString());
        HolderBusNumbers[ArrayPosition] = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

I am working it for a hours, can you help with what i'm doing wrong :/ ??

Comment: Use HashMap to save the data in the Method onTextChanged(...) and display from the map on scroll

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Created a reference integer in the static ViewHolder that holds the position of clicked item in listview. Then in text watcher i set the string of the item that exists in the viewholder.reference position of my list.
So, static is helping with that job.
The following code is the one that worked!

```
static class ViewHolder{

    TextView FlightTimeTextView;
    EditText BusNumberEditText;
    int Reference;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) AdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_order, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.FlightTimeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemFlightTimeTextView);
        holder.BusNumberEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busNumberEditText);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Order order = Orders.get(position);

    holder.Reference = position;
    holder.FlightTimeTextView.setText(order.getFlightTime());
    holder.BusNumberEditText.setText(order.getBusNumber());
    holder.BusNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Orders.get(holder.Reference).setBusNumber(s.toString());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Move your textwatcher code inside the getView()

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    ArrayPosition = position;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) AdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_order, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.FlightTimeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemFlightTimeTextView);
        holder.BusNumberEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busNumberEditText);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Order order = Orders.get(position);
    holder.FlightTimeTextView.setText(order.getFlightTime());

    holder.BusNumberEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    Log.d("String in array String", HolderBusNumbers[position]);
    holder.BusNumberEditText.setText(HolderBusNumbers[position]);

   holder.BusNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                Log.d("TextWatcher", s.toString());
        HolderBusNumbers[ArrayPosition] = s.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Also didn't work, text watcher override because edittext view is the same because of viewholder and being again called when scroll down. I have data in the array string but it is not appropriate called.

Comment: can take help from this link http://www.webplusandroid.com/creating-listview-with-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/

Comment: This trick with the ViewHolder was really good !
I create a reference in viewholder that keeps position and use this reference to set the string on TextWatcher. It worked with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HashMap object which will store data if EditText contains value or not.And when you scroll the listview,it will be rendered again by calling its getView method along with the text associated with each edittext.

1. Define HashMap global into adapter

   ```
   public static HashMap<Integer,String> myList=new HashMap<Integer,String>();



   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       ViewHolder holder;
       ArrayPosition = position;

       if(convertView == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) AdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_order, parent, false);

           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.FlightTimeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemFlightTimeTextView);
           holder.BusNumberEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busNumberEditText);

           convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {

           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       final Order order = Orders.get(position);
       holder.FlightTimeTextView.setText(order.getFlightTime());

       Log.d("String in array String", HolderBusNumbers[position]);

       holder.BusNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
               int before, int count) {

       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
               int count, int after) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           myList.put(pos,s.toString.trim());
       }
       });

       holder.BusNumberEditText.setText(myList.get(position));



       return convertView;
       }
   ```

It would be helpful to you!!

Comment: Didn't work, when scroll down text watcher of changed edittext is called and changes his text. Scrolling back it is empty (from debugging)

Comment: You can take help from this link http://www.webplusandroid.com/creating-listview-with-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

im also a beginner in android but try to use SimpleAdapter for displaying data

Answer (score -2):

put your Textwatcher inside getView() function of adapter , make position(first argument of getview function) final int and in onTextChange do this

```
HolderBusNumbers[position] = s.toString();
```